# Bootsrap - Form inside a popover inside a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to add this feature to my login modal and I just can't get it to work right. I would love some help on this as I can't wrap my head around it.

I would like to make the "x" button in the title of the popover close the popover, the form only works when the modal is closed. I really want this to work when the modal is open. This is the code I'm working with.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="loginModalLabel">Login</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body-login">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="usernameInput">Username</label>
                    <input type="username" class="form-control" id="usernameInput" placeholder="Username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="passwordInput">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordInput" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                </label>
                <label>

                <p class="forgot-password"><a href="#" id="passwordReset" data-html="true" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" title="Password Reset <button type='button' class='close' id='close-popover' data-toggle='popover' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>" data-placement="right" data-content="
                <p>Please Enter the Email Adress linked to your account, well send you a password reset right away!</p>
                <form>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <input type='newEmail' class='form-control' placeholder='Email Adress'>
                    </div>
                    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-success btn-block'>Reset!</button>
                </form>
                ">Forgot Password?</a></p>

                </label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <h4>- OR -</h4>
            <a href="#collapseSignUp" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseSignUp"><h1>Sign Up</h1></a>
            <div class="collapse" id="collapseSignUp">
                <div class="well">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="newUser" class="form-control" placeholder="New Username">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="newName" class="form-control" placeholder="First & Last Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="newEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Adress">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="newPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="New Password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox sub-check">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox"> Sign Up for our newsletter? <p class="sub">No spam + Tonnes of free stuff.</p>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Sign Up</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

If there is a reason why this isnt working properly, I would love to know. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear, based on what I understood, you could have popover with html content with close button, this way.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#loginModal').modal('show');
 $("#passwordReset").popover({
  container: '#loginModal',
    html: true,
 template: '<div class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"><button class="closePopover"><span aria-hidden=""true">&times;</span></button></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>',
  title: '<span class="text-info"><strong>Password Reset</strong></span>'+
                '<button type="button" id="close" class="close" onclick="$(&quot;#passwordReset&quot;).popover(&quot;hide&quot;);">&times;</button>',
 content: function() {
          return $('#popover-content').html();
        }
});
});
```

```css
.popover-title .close{
 margin-top: -3px;
 position: absolute;
 right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="loginModalLabel">Login</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body-login">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="usernameInput">Username</label>
                    <input type="username" class="form-control" id="usernameInput" placeholder="Username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="passwordInput">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordInput" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                </label>
                <label>

                <p class="forgot-password">
     <a href="#" id="passwordReset">Forgot Password?</a></p>

                </label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <h4>- OR -</h4>
            <a href="#collapseSignUp" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseSignUp"><h1>Sign Up</h1></a>
            <div class="collapse" id="collapseSignUp">
                <div class="well">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="newUser" class="form-control" placeholder="New Username">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="newName" class="form-control" placeholder="First & Last Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="newEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Adress">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="newPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="New Password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox sub-check">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox"> Sign Up for our newsletter? <p class="sub">No spam + Tonnes of free stuff.</p>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Sign Up</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
 </div>
 <div id="popover-content" class="hide">
                <p>Please Enter the Email Adress linked to your account, well send you a password reset right away!</p>
                <form>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <input type='email' name="newEmail" class='form-control' placeholder='Email Adress'>
                    </div>
                    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-success btn-block'>Reset!</button>
                </form>  
 </div> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please comment if you have any questions.

Comment: I ran your snippet, and the same problem seems to occur. You can't enter anything in the form without the modal closed. Do you know how to make the form selectable when the modal is open?

Comment: I updated my code and fixed the issue, you can also check it here https://jsbin.com/coliqit/edit?html,js,output.

Comment: I am using a trigger for this modal, when using your code it seems to open immediately. how do I link it to this? `<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</a>`

Comment: It's opening immediately because I added `$('#loginModal').modal('show');` on `$(document).ready()` and about triggering popover on hover, you have to `trigger: 'hover',` on `popover` options object, here is an example of that https://jsbin.com/coliqit/edit?html,js,output, though you shouldn't do this, otherwise user won't be able to use the popover form. Hope this helps.

Comment: I thank you so much for this! I really appreciate the help with this as I know very little of javascript. I wouldn't have been able to do it without you.

Comment: Happy to help, make sure to check documentation of anything you are working with, also check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript to learn more about JavaScript.